# How can I improve this postgresql query for calculating "Aroon Indicator"

Tags: postgresql, technical-indicator

I am attempting to write a postgresql query to calculate the "[Aroon Indicator](https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/112814/what-aroon-indicator-formula-and-how-indicator-calculated.asp)" of financial candlestick data. All my other attempts at other technical analysis metrics on the same dataset have run quickly, yet this query is running at 50 seconds. I'm thinking there has to be some efficiency I am missing.

In plain english the "Aroon Indicator" is "calculated based on the length of time since a particular security or index has reached a recent high."

So for a 25 day period, the formula is ((25 - (number_of_days_since_the_high_price_in_last_25 days) / 25) * 100.

Here is the query I wrote that seems to work, but is slow:

```
WITH crypto_w_row_num AS (
    SELECT 
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY symbol, granularity ORDER BY period DESC) as row_num
    FROM crypto
)
SELECT 
    c1.*,
    c2.price_high,
    ((25 - (c1.row_num - c2.row_num)) / 25.0) * 100 AS aroon_bullish,
    ((25 - (c1.row_num - c3.row_num)) / 25.0) * 100 AS aroon_bearish
FROM crypto_w_row_num c1
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT * 
    FROM crypto_w_row_num 
    WHERE row_num > c1.row_num - 25 AND row_num <= c1.row_num
    AND symbol = c1.symbol AND granularity = c1.granularity
    ORDER BY price_high DESC, period DESC
    LIMIT 1
) c2 ON TRUE
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT * 
    FROM crypto_w_row_num 
    WHERE row_num > c1.row_num - 25 AND row_num <= c1.row_num
    AND symbol = c1.symbol AND granularity = c1.granularity
    ORDER BY price_high ASC, period DESC
    LIMIT 1
) c3 ON TRUE
WHERE c1.symbol = 'SHIB-USD' AND c1.granularity = '300' ORDER BY c1.period;
```

Before I explore indexing strategies to speed this up, is there some fundamentally different way I should approach this?

Table DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE crypto (
    period timestamp without time zone,
    symbol character varying,
    granularity character varying,
    price_low numeric,
    price_high numeric,
    price_open numeric,
    price_close numeric,
    volume numeric,
    CONSTRAINT crypto_pkey PRIMARY KEY (period, symbol, granularity)
);
```

Data example:

```
INSERT INTO "public"."crypto"("period","symbol","granularity","price_low","price_high","price_open","price_close","volume")
VALUES
(E'2021-09-09 11:10:00',E'SHIB-USD',E'300',0.00001,0.00001399,0.00001,0.00001399,2593611248),
(E'2021-09-09 11:15:00',E'SHIB-USD',E'300',0.0000081,0.00003111,0.000013,0.00000955,25317710205),
(E'2021-09-09 11:20:00',E'SHIB-USD',E'300',0.000006,0.00001,0.0000095,0.0000072,30067341828),
(E'2021-09-09 11:25:00',E'SHIB-USD',E'300',0.00000601,0.00000797,0.0000072,0.00000748,21321324571),
(E'2021-09-09 11:30:00',E'SHIB-USD',E'300',0.00000738,0.00000748,0.00000747,0.00000744,16398559934),
(E'2021-09-09 11:35:00',E'SHIB-USD',E'300',0.00000725,0.00000776,0.00000746,0.00000734,34220044532),
(E'2021-09-09 11:40:00',E'SHIB-USD',E'300',0.0000073,0.0000074,0.00000732,0.00000737,21881556898),
(E'2021-09-09 11:45:00',E'SHIB-USD',E'300',0.00000736,0.00000748,0.00000737,0.00000747,13908049922),
(E'2021-09-09 11:50:00',E'SHIB-USD',E'300',0.00000746,0.0000155,0.00000747,0.0000123,54739385481),
(E'2021-09-09 11:55:00',E'SHIB-USD',E'300',0.0000099,0.0000155,0.000013,0.000013,67925125159),
(E'2021-09-09 12:00:00',E'SHIB-USD',E'300',0.00001152,0.0000579,0.00001277,0.00005,91181753605),
(E'2021-09-09 12:05:00',E'SHIB-USD',E'300',0.00003,0.00007499,0.000055,0.00003588,70897539508),
(E'2021-09-09 12:10:00',E'SHIB-USD',E'300',0.000032,0.00005,0.000035,0.00004222,67743029887),
(E'2021-09-09 12:15:00',E'SHIB-USD',E'300',0.000035,0.0000429,0.000042,0.000035,47572071936),
(E'2021-09-09 12:20:00',E'SHIB-USD',E'300',0.0000206,0.00003799,0.000035,0.00003499,54289742296),
(E'2021-09-09 12:25:00',E'SHIB-USD',E'300',0.000027,0.000035,0.00003498,0.00002701,37194821296),
(E'2021-09-09 12:30:00',E'SHIB-USD',E'300',0.000025,0.00003799,0.00002701,0.00003798,42206077664),
(E'2021-09-09 12:35:00',E'SHIB-USD',E'300',0.00003442,0.000045,0.00003442,0.00004201,51968895955),
(E'2021-09-09 12:40:00',E'SHIB-USD',E'300',0.00003481,0.00004512,0.00004202,0.00003781,36145026338),
(E'2021-09-09 12:45:00',E'SHIB-USD',E'300',0.000037,0.00005718,0.00003732,0.000056,62897590107),
(E'2021-09-09 12:50:00',E'SHIB-USD',E'300',0.00005,0.0000578,0.000055,0.00005047,49399828385),
(E'2021-09-09 12:55:00',E'SHIB-USD',E'300',0.000041,0.0000548,0.00005,0.0000509,48604886186),
(E'2021-09-09 13:00:00',E'SHIB-USD',E'300',0.000048,0.00006,0.00005,0.00005801,43411455146),
(E'2021-09-09 13:05:00',E'SHIB-USD',E'300',0.00005804,0.00009,0.00005991,0.00006985,86353267664),
(E'2021-09-09 13:10:00',E'SHIB-USD',E'300',0.0000671,0.000085,0.00006983,0.00007713,51822852940),
(E'2021-09-09 13:15:00',E'SHIB-USD',E'300',0.00006455,0.00008148,0.000076,0.00007542,46955190713),
(E'2021-09-09 13:20:00',E'SHIB-USD',E'300',0.0000699,0.0000785,0.00007542,0.000073,30770645915),
(E'2021-09-09 13:25:00',E'SHIB-USD',E'300',0.00006514,0.000073,0.00007296,0.000066,12935376159),
(E'2021-09-09 13:30:00',E'SHIB-USD',E'300',0.00005004,0.000066,0.00006541,0.00005012,24877546170),
(E'2021-09-09 13:35:00',E'SHIB-USD',E'300',0.00005,0.00005808,0.00005029,0.00005807,20687029957);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Every part of your query depends on the CTE `crypto_w_row_num`, except the final `where` clause. That is perhaps eliminating much of the work done by the main query. What happens if you move that `where` into the CTE and eliminate as much as possible before the joins. You can run `explain analyze` on each version then see if they produce the same results. Admittedly it is difficult to make a good judgement with only 38 rows, all of which satisfy the criteria, But I ran both explains any. Your original version run time 4.69ms, revised version 1.97ms. The results appear the same, but that is just a quick glance.

```
with crypto_w_row_num as (
    select 
        *,
        row_number() over(partition by symbol, granularity order by period desc) as row_num
    from crypto
where symbol = 'SHIB-USD' and granularity = '300' order by period    
)
select 
    c1.*,
    c2.price_high,
    ((25 - (c1.row_num - c2.row_num)) / 25.0) * 100 as aroon_bullish,
    ((25 - (c1.row_num - c3.row_num)) / 25.0) * 100 as aroon_bearish
from crypto_w_row_num c1
left join lateral (
    select * 
    from crypto_w_row_num 
    where row_num > c1.row_num - 25 and row_num <= c1.row_num
    and symbol = c1.symbol and granularity = c1.granularity
    order by price_high desc, period desc
    limit 1
) c2 on true
left join lateral (
    select * 
    from crypto_w_row_num 
    where row_num > c1.row_num - 25 and row_num <= c1.row_num
    and symbol = c1.symbol and granularity = c1.granularity
    order by price_high asc, period desc
    limit 1
) c3 on true
;
```

Playing with indexes seems unlikely to help and you already have an index containing the only columns directly queried, perhaps changing the order:

```
CONSTRAINT crypto_pkey PRIMARY KEY(symbol, granularity,period )
```

Additionally, unless you actually need all columns in the result, do not do `select *` just list to columns needed. With a large result set memory management comes into play - and the more needed the more time it takes.